# Apache SVN LDAP Permissions

Tags: apache, svn

Trying to secure a folder in an SVN Repo on Centos 7 using SVN 1.7.1

So the conf I am using is below, But it seems to be giving all AD users access, anyone got a suggestion of where I gone wrong in the config. I commented out all other configs at the moment while sorting this folder out, will re add the others onces it sorted so I only working on a simpified system while working on it.

```
<Location /srv/svn/Secure_Sequences>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /srv/svn/repositories/Secure_Sequences
        AuthName "Secure Sequences"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=rdsvn,OU=06 - Generic,OU=01 - UK,OU=RD Users,OU=Radio Design,DC=Tracabz,DC=tracinternational,DC=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "<SECRET>"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.5.11:389/dc=Tracabz,dc=tracinternational,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
        Require ldap-group CN=SVNSecure,OU=Confidential,OU=Management,OU=Network Shares,OU=UK,OU=RD - Security Groups,OU=Radio Design,DC=Tracabz,DC=tracinternational,DC=com
</Location>
```